# Как сделать нестандартный селект с возможностью множественного выбора в виде чекбокса

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Всем доброго дня, кому вечера. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь плагин, чтобы  можно было сделать нестандартный селект с возможностью множественного выбора в виде чекбоксов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [JQuery UI Multiselect](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)
2. [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)